# Tumblr API - Jumblr for Android [OAuthConnectionException]

Tags: android, oauth, tumblr

I realized that Jumblr, a Tumblr APi for Android isn't well documented on how do we actually go about implementing one. I've successfully authorize my account on my app. That's all. According to [Jumblr's README](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr), all you have to do is to

```
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("consumer_key", "consumer_secret");
client.setToken("oauth_token", "oauth_token_secret");
```

where consumer key and secret is already set in my app and oauth_token and token_secret is got by the app when user logs in.
However, I'm getting errors like

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
```

Full logcat:

```
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.example.tumblr/dev.example.tumblr.MainActivity}: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896): Caused by: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:70)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:76)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at dev.example.tumblr.library.request.RequestBuilder.get(RequestBuilder.java:71)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at dev.example.tumblr.library.JumblrClient.user(JumblrClient.java:65)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at dev.example.tumblr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    ... 11 more
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:29)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:117)
08-12 19:55:03.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27896):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:66)
```

I know I have to do something with Oauth. But what is it? I have little experience in previous Oauth for Twitter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and not OAuth. Starting with Android 3.0, all network operations must be run on background threads. Put your calls to Jumblr in an AsyncTask or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Unable to get user info**

**Using:**
consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(APP_CONSUMER_KEY, APP_CONSUMER_SECRET);
provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("request token url",
"acess token url", "authorize url");
provider.setOAuth10a(true);
try
{
authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
}

**After getting token and secret, I am calling**

api = new JumblrClient(TumblrLoginActivity.APP_CONSUMER_KEY,TumblrLoginActivity.APP_CONSUMER_SECRET);
api.setToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());

LOG error:

org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.